# include method in gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

What does `include` in the settings.gradle actual is? Is it a method or something else. In any way there are neither method nor property with such name in the gradle [Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html). For instance I've written the following settings file to build all my project together:

```
include 'MP', 'API'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a method. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#include%28java.lang.String[]%29) is its api doc (that I simply found by browsing the index of the javadoc).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `settings.gradle` is also a *normal* gradle script.

Comment: Hm... but my question is why we can call it just as `include(ArgumentList)`. I suspect a name used in the settings.gradle is looked up whithin the Setting interface, is it?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. The same way it's done with Project in the build file.

Comment: Generally speaking, each script and configuration block within that script is backed by some object whose methods and properties can be accessed without qualification.